# Drawable Animation With Gesture To Pause, Go Forward and Backward

Tags: android, animation, gesture, animationdrawable

I wan't to make something like a DrawableAnimation, displaying an image sequence. This Drawable animation could be played automatically, and also managed with a gesture recognition to read Forward and backward, slow or pause the animation etc...
I did't found the possibility to read backward in a drawable Animation.
How to make this, any Idea ? Or perhaps a link to a tuto that do something similar.
Thank's.